# Two stylesheets, one hover effect

Tags: css, wordpress, class, wordpress-theming

I'm working on my wordpress website, I recently got this new theme called Visia. After a search for days I finally found out where the hover effects for the circle around the social buttons was located. But there's only one problem: the icons have their own CSS file. And I want both circle (border-color) and icon (color, they have an icon font) to change color on just one hover.
Now I got this changed in the icons.css

```
.icon-linkedin:hover {
    border-color:#06C;
    opacity::1;
    color:#06C; 
}
```

the other one has no hover yet, because I tried to refer to that class (style.css) to icons.css

```
.social-links a:hover {
    ???
}
```

The borders should change color the same color as the icons (because there are different social links, there are different colors)

If anyone could help, would be great...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Simply overwrite it like so:

```
.icon-linkedin:hover {
    border-color:007bb6;
    color:007bb6; 
}
```

And add `!important` if needed:

```
.icon-linkedin:hover {
    border-color:007bb6 !important;
    color:007bb6 !important; 
}
```

Comment: so you mean I should add the icon-linkedin class to the style.css?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it by removing the border from some other class (the one who actually gave the border) and added it to an icon class that was already there. I also added a hover to that class which made it possible to change both color and border-color.